# Shopify issue using Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

So this is probably really basic but i have been searching inside and out trying to find the answer, on my site i have a cart and the title of the cart is what i want to change, however in the source it looks like:

```
<h1 class="text-center">{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
```

cart.general.title i cannot find any reference to this so i can edit the title, sure i could probably just replace that string with my title but that may not be the efficient approach.

Where can i edit cart.general variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the language variables. They can accessed in Settings-> Checkout->Checkout Language